# String Functions on Unnested Arrays in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to find all instances of rows where one of the array items contains a value, ignoring the case in Google BigQuery.

I'm able to do this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `my_bq_project.my_bq_dataset.my_table`
WHERE
  (
      'AAA' IN UNNEST(array_1.array_2.some_text)
  )
```

This works well for finding `'AAA'` inside `array_1.array_2.some_text`. But I would like to also find `'aaa'`, `'Aaa'`, and so forth.

But this does not work:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `my_bq_project.my_bq_dataset.my_table`
WHERE
  (
      'AAA' IN UNNEST(LOWER(array_1.array_2.some_text))
  )
```

And I would like to refrain from duplicating the where statement (adding where conditions for `'AaA'`, `'aaa'`, etc.).

Is there a way to apply string functions like `LOWER` on struct fields that are in arrays in BigQuery SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below approach

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `my_bq_project.my_bq_dataset.my_table`
WHERE LOWER('AAA') IN (
  SELECT LOWER(some_text)
  FROM UNNEST(array_1) a, UNNEST(a.array_2)
)
```

Comment: glad it worked for you. consider also voting up the answer then :o)